# Zend-form without Zend-Framework MVC - viewscript isn't displaying elements, but they exists and are displayed by var_dump()

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

When I try to do something like

```
 <?=$this->element->mailCiteCheck?>
```

nothing is displaying.

However, when I do:

```
<?=var_dump($this->element->mailCiteCheck);?>
```

I get:

```
object(Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox)#118 (33) {
  ["checked"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["helper"]=>
  string(12) "formCheckbox"
  ["options"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["checkedValue"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["uncheckedValue"]=>
```

And so on... so how can I display elements of this form?

And when I do

```
<?=$this->element->mailCiteCheck;die();?>
```

I get this warning:

> ViewHelper decorator cannot render without a registered view object

Comment: Ok, problem solved, I didn't overwrite setView method, although I thought I did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was to set view to all form elements:

```
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $view->addScriptPath(APPLICATION_FORM_SCRIPT_PATH);
    $view->addBasePath(APPLICATION_SCRIPT_PATH);
    $replyForm = new Form_MailReply();
    $replyForm->setView($view);
    foreach ($replyForm as $item){
        $item->setView($view);
    }
    $replyForm->render($view);
```

Answer (score 4):

As noted in [the link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.quickstart.html#zend.form.quickstart.render) provided by @Hikaru:

> By default, Zend_Form and Zend_Form_Element will attempt to use the view object initialized in the `ViewRenderer`

So instead of overriding the form's `render()` method or manually calling `$form->setView($view)`, an alternate approach is to just set the view into the `ViewRenderer`, possibly during Bootstrap:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer')->view = $view;
```

Comment: This is only possible if the controller component of ZF is to be used. This component is part of the MVC implementation of ZF which the OP is not using.

Comment: @Hikaru-Shindo: D'oh! That is a very good point; I missed that part of the OP question. ;-) I will note that when I have used `Zend_Form` without the full ZF MVC stack, it was still possible to make the static call above. Internally, it creates a `ViewRenderer` instance and assigns the view. Made everything much easier and allowed the form to fall back to using the view stashed cozily away in the `ViewRenderer`. But, as in most things, YMMV. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Zend_Form depends on Zend_View. You also need to use the Zend_View class to make it work.

You may read something on this topic [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.quickstart.html#zend.form.quickstart.render).

A possible example how to achieve it:

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$form = new My_Form();

echo $form->render($view);
```